# Heroku app working locally but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

So my app is working fine locally when i run `rails s`. But now, after following all the steps to deploy a rails app on [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction) I get and error message which looks like this:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

Her are my logs:
***UPDATED LOGS***

```
Your version of git is 2.1.3. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
2015-03-14T21:12:51.997571+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:12:51.997571+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:19.134274+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:19.134274+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, SECRET_KEY_BASE, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES config vars by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:19.625662+00:00 heroku[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:19.625662+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:19.688176+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN resource by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:19.688176+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:20.066203+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 3b816ca by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:20.066203+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:19.998561+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:23.040161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 48503 -e production`
2015-03-14T21:15:27.093590+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-14 21:15:27] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-03-14T21:15:27.093615+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-14 21:15:27] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-03-14T21:15:27.094103+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-14 21:15:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=48503
2015-03-14T21:15:27.423844+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-14T21:15:34.363830+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:15:38.335944+00:00 heroku[run.2766]: Awaiting client
2015-03-14T21:15:38.359537+00:00 heroku[run.2766]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-03-14T21:15:38.728584+00:00 heroku[run.2766]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-14T21:15:43.782436+00:00 heroku[run.2766]: State changed from up to complete
2015-03-14T21:15:43.775527+00:00 heroku[run.2766]: Process exited with status 0
2015-03-14T21:15:54.179089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=82e3063b-b8e1-46eb-a9b9-5e704550a54e fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=103ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-14T21:15:54.374677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=d424ab6e-c138-4480-906d-b6aff3c09c65 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-03-14T21:17:20.783060+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:17:27.739108+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=f59551ee-5933-4c8f-9539-57ed00e20f98 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-14T21:17:27.915141+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=4bb5168c-3346-4978-9ed7-8f6704b62e56 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-14T21:21:30.932085+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:seed` by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:21:35.428817+00:00 heroku[run.5383]: Awaiting client
2015-03-14T21:21:35.459636+00:00 heroku[run.5383]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:seed`
2015-03-14T21:21:35.929573+00:00 heroku[run.5383]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-14T21:21:47.205393+00:00 heroku[run.5383]: State changed from up to complete
2015-03-14T21:21:47.203404+00:00 heroku[run.5383]: Process exited with status 0
2015-03-14T21:21:57.710902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=9a08f605-b770-4fd1-9323-9f5b677001c0 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=164ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-14T21:21:57.857105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=f76aeb03-5236-47d8-be1b-fdbab76f3c28 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-14T21:30:17.463789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=c17d7b6e-311e-4ce0-9ad2-87ae01ec3656 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-14T21:30:17.642656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=ffd182f8-64bb-444e-b2aa-b9d9fe0bd4ec fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-14T21:38:08.147712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=3cc214bb-475f-4781-8d61-3b2a46a45421 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-14T21:38:08.372266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=b20c8c26-574f-4c9d-a8e7-f013add43778 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-14T21:43:52.750349+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=7581e9a5-50d8-4e45-b892-b64a65d279ff fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=88ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-14T21:43:52.958597+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=bf056489-ff42-47ba-a2e2-330466bbbd40 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-14T21:55:40.308371+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=479398b9-f7c5-457a-86b8-bb6e9c84e53b fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-14T21:55:40.493762+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=03958579-9b24-40dc-ab55-40d4dd2073d0 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-14T21:57:46.150237+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:57:46.150237+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2492c30 by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:57:46.514788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-03-14T21:57:48.984426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-03-14T21:57:49.487721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 10692 -e production`
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612797+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612794+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612796+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612806+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612787+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-14 21:57:49] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612800+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:35:in `run'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612807+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612811+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612813+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612814+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612821+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-14 21:57:49] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612865+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-14 21:57:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-03-14T21:57:49.654168+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612804+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612802+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612799+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.654175+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:48503
2015-03-14T21:57:49.612803+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-03-14T21:57:49.654177+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-03-14T21:57:49.654179+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-03-14T21:57:49.654180+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-03-14T21:57:50.507456+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-03-14T21:57:54.350749+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-14 21:57:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-03-14T21:57:54.350836+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-14 21:57:54] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-03-14T21:57:54.351279+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-14 21:57:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=10692
2015-03-14T21:57:54.585341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-14T21:58:03.215044+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=357754bb-9323-4cb4-aeaa-90364f5f95a9 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=288ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-14T21:58:23.367804+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sophie.debenedetto@gmail.com
2015-03-14T21:58:26.564841+00:00 heroku[run.8204]: Awaiting client
2015-03-14T21:58:26.589466+00:00 heroku[run.8204]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-03-14T21:58:26.975103+00:00 heroku[run.8204]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-14T21:58:31.108666+00:00 heroku[run.8204]: State changed from up to complete
2015-03-14T21:58:31.091879+00:00 heroku[run.8204]: Process exited with status 0
2015-03-14T21:58:38.338030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=456890b6-c674-492c-b127-d6d3ff2e50c0 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=45ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-14T21:58:39.489025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-6653.herokuapp.com request_id=90df538f-f641-484b-9c0f-d1163bae0006 fwd="71.183.68.143" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=31ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Please let me know if you need any more information, I'll be more than happy to provide you with that!

Comment: Does it work locally if you run `foreman start`?

Comment: what is `foreman start`?

Comment: An easy option for running your apps locally. It comes with [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/).

Comment: just tried that gave me `ERROR  Procfile does not exist.`

Comment: You will need a Procfile. Take a look at Heroku [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) how to create one

Comment: Why would I need that? I pushed apps before to Heroku and never was I asked to do that

Comment: @kostans3k - foreman is not required for heroku?

Comment: No i'm talking about `Procfile`

Comment: `Procfile` is used by foreman and is not required - it is only needed when you have more complex startup process (like having background workers or services)

Comment: Got you. Do you have any idea why the app isn't working on heroku? here is my git repo if that help [trial](https://github.com/SophieDeBenedetto/trial)

Comment: It seems you're missing some gems that are required by heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems. `rails_12factor` might not completely solve the problem, but at least should give you more details in you logfile (it is required for rails 4 applications)

Comment: Also heroku only accepts applications running with postgres - sqlite will not work there. Yep, I know, they offering a lot but they also limit you a lot.

Comment: ok ok, I just updated my post to include the newly logs when running
 ` heroku logs`